# Transparent clipping mask in Adobe Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a rectangle shape with no fill and no outline and one line of a text. I want to clip this text by the shape. If the shape has no fill, the text will disappear. If the shape has white fill, I will lost a content under this shaped text. How to get around this?

**UPDATE:**

[image]

I need transparent shape, not white. White background hides green leafs.
If I set up it as 'no fill, no outline', it stops to work as clipping mask.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can you post an image or screenshot showing what you are trying to achieve, or what has failed?

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish. If you want something to hide the leaves, you need to mask the *leaves* not the text. And if you want text to not be visible, set it's opacity to 0% or turn off the layer. Essentially, I don't understand why you are trying to *mask text* merely to change its color. Why can't you just change the text color?

Comment: Are you trying to create a "hole" in the leaves so if the text is not visible, the leaves still have transparent areas where text used to be? Basically "punching out" the text from the leaves?

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I still don't know what you want to achieve. Why do you need a clipping mask?  What are you trying to mask?

Comment: I am trying to trim B, H, L and P letters. Maybe there is another way to achieve it?

Comment: Ah . . . that's the missing information!!  Anyway, Scott has it - you want a layer mask, not a clipping mask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are merely trying to clip the ascenders and descenders to the edge of that white rectangle... All you need is a *standard layer mask* applied to the text layer.

Here.. red is the full text, black shows the masked text.

[image]

It's simply a regular layer mask. No need for any shapes or clipping masks.

[image]

Comment: +1 yet another XY Problem solved.

Comment: We will see `:)` no real way to tell without a response. `:)`